# Merging .txt files from 2002-2020 for bulk financial data into one table

Tags: r, merge

I am very new to R and RStudio and currently running codes from Machine Learning with R Quick Start Guide to review bulk financial data. I am running the following code chunk in R:

```
library(readr)

t <- proc.time()

for (i in 1:length(myfiles)){

tables<-list() 
myfiles <- list.files(path = "~/MachineLearning/Banks_model", pattern = "20",  full.names = TRUE)

filelist <- list.files(path = myfiles[i], pattern = "*",  full.names = TRUE)
filelist<-filelist[1:(length(filelist)-1)]

for (h in 1:length(filelist)){

#assuming tab separated values with a header    
aux = as.data.frame(read_delim(filelist[h],  "\t", escape_double = FALSE, col_names = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE, skip = 2))

variables<-colnames(as.data.frame(read_delim(filelist[h],  "\t", escape_double = FALSE, col_names = TRUE, trim_ws = TRUE, skip = 0)))

colnames(aux)<-variables

dataset_name<-paste("aux",h,sep='')
tables[[h]]<-assign(dataset_name,aux)

}

final_data_name<-paste("year",i+2001,sep='')
union <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE, 
    by=c("ID RSSD","Reporting Period")), tables, accumulate=FALSE)

assign(final_data_name,union)
rm(list=ls()[! ls() %in% c(ls(pattern="year*"),"tables","t")])
}

proc.time() - t
```

and received the following error:

Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns

The traceback in RStudio is as follows:
7.
stop(ngettext(sum(bad), "'by' must specify a uniquely valid column", "'by' must specify uniquely valid columns"), domain = NA)
6.
fix.by(by.x, x)
5.
merge.data.frame(x, y, all = TRUE, by = c("ID RSSD", "Reporting Period"))
4.
merge(x, y, all = TRUE, by = c("ID RSSD", "Reporting Period"))
3.
merge(x, y, all = TRUE, by = c("ID RSSD", "Reporting Period"))
2.
f(init, x[[i]])
1.
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE, by = c("ID RSSD", "Reporting Period")), tables, accumulate = FALSE)

Any idea what the fix is please?

Comment: What is it your desired outcome? To me your code seems unnecessary complex. Could you maybe give an idea of the data as well?

Comment: Hello Annet! Yes, the codes are from from Sanz Machine Learning with R Quick Start Guide. Outcome is to merge .txt files into one table for analysis. str(aux)
'data.frame': 20411 obs. of  47 variables:
 $ Reporting Period: chr  "3/31/2020 11:59:59 PM" "3/31/2020 11:59:59 PM" "3/31/2020 11:59:59 PM" "3/31/2020 11:59:59 PM" ...
 $ ID RSSD         : num  37 242 279 354 457 ...
 $ UBPR3210        : num  17026 5108 31366 1498 4384 ...
 $ UBPR4340        : num  124 171 265 -29 230 ...

Comment: Personally I would put all file names in a named character and use map to read all the individual files. They will all be in a list, out of which  you can make a data frame. However, it is kinda hard to come up with working code without the files and such.